# Why does modifying a Buffer slice modify the original?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The following modifies a slice of a `Buffer`.

In doing so, it modifies the *original* `Buffer` too. If I were to perform a similar operation on an `Array`, then the original would remain unchanged.

So is this behavior the result of the specific implementation of the `slice` method on Node.js' `Buffer`?

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile(__filename, (err, buffer) => {
  const tag = buffer.slice(-2, -1);
  tag[0] = 'B';

  console.log(buffer.toString());
});

 // TAG: A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs says

> Returns a new Buffer that references the same memory as the original, but offset and cropped by the start and end indices. Note: Modifying the new Buffer slice will **modify the memory in the original Buffer** because the allocated memory of the two objects overlap.

https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_slice_start_end